# How do I setup each IT Support member to be able to remove certain workstation from Domain?

Tags: active-directory, permissions

This is the situation:
We are in a Corp environment, several IT Support guys, several branches.
We have assigned branches individually (and their workstations under AD as well).
Question: Is there any way to limit each Admin guy (IT support limited already to his/her group of workstation via GP) and enable him/her to REMOVE any of those workstation, in order later on to ADD it back? (example: windows reinstall)?
Thanks, this will help me to claim it if there exist, with the right answer. (I'm not Server Admin as you can see) =D

Comment: I believe non-admins can all remove computers from the domain, they just cannot add them back....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, it is called Active Directory Delegated Authority.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2007.02.activedirectory.aspx